# Elastic Beanstalk won't find/use my requirements.txt file and so it cannot find the module "django"

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, requirements.txt

I'm trying to deploy a python web app using django and have successfully setup the EB environment but for some reason, it's not using my requirements.txt file to install the required modules (django and pytz). I see no reference to an invalid requirements.txt so I don't think that's the issue. Here is a file hierarchy and the latest log.

```
FirstWebApp/
    .elasticbeanstalk/
        config.yml
    mysite/
        #..
    polls/
        #..
    db.sqlite3
    manage.py
    requirements.txt


[Sat Sep 01 21:08:01.508757 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 7866] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.599699 2018] [suexec:notice] [pid 11160] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.615594 2018] [so:warn] [pid 11160] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.617699 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11160] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.617712 2018] [http2:warn] [pid 11160] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.618263 2018] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 11160] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.618326 2018] [:warn] [pid 11160] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.618331 2018] [:warn] [pid 11160] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.5.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.620634 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 11160] AH00163: Apache/2.4.33 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:02.620651 2018] [core:notice] [pid 11160] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:05.381076 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:05.381116 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:05.381287 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:05.381309 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:05.381313 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:05.381326 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:06.384353 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:06.384403 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:06.384505 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:06.384528 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:252]   File "/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:06.384531 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:252]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:06.384560 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:252] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:07.387609 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:07.387656 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:07.387725 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:07.387744 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304]   File "/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:07.387748 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:07.387761 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:08.390656 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:08.390700 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] mod_wsgi (pid=11165): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:08.390770 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:08.390790 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304]   File "/opt/python/current/app/mysite/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:08.390793 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat Sep 01 21:08:08.390807 2018] [:error] [pid 11165] [remote 127.0.0.1:2304] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: What's in your requirements.txt for django? Can you successfully import other packages listed in requirements.txt?

Comment: Wouldn't the yaml be in a .ebextensions dir so that your file structure would resemble something similar to the example here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Comment: I figured out the issue. I hadn't commited the requirements.txt file and apparently EB only takes whatever was in the latest commit when you deploy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to commit the `requirements.txt` file. Django only looks at whatever files have been committed.